# What is the difference succinct and unclear?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6221/when-can-be-the-fiscal-multiplier-negative) was put on hold as unclear. What is the reason for this? Is it because the OP did not define what he meant by fiscal multiplier? I only found one definition via Google and that was quite clear.

Comment: A agree that the question seems clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an English mistake in the title, and there is no redundancy in the question itself which shows poor effort at expressing oneself as well as possible, which is why I put it on hold as unclear. If you edit the title to correct the mistake, I would vote to reopen.

More generally: I don't mind very short questions as long as they're crystal-clear. This one is not.